# How can I fill NA values in my NDVI Data?

Tags: python, r, ndvi, filter, time-series

I have been trying for weeks now to clean my NDVI data. I know that I have to apply Savitzky-Golay filter to smoothen my data. But before that, I have to fill the missing values in my data. I am trying to do this by loess polynomial regression method as suggested in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279354/ndvi-time-series-with-missing-values?rq=1). But I have many missing values in my data at the beginning and at the end i.e. NA values on the absolute tail of time-series data.
Here is my sample data:

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this problem. My data consists ndvi values for different pixels of different plots of a particular crop. I request you guys to please help me out on this.

Comment: `NaN` is not the same as `NA`. Can you make a simulated data set that fails in the way you see with your own data?

Comment: I am reading this data from a csv file and it is giving me NAN for all the places with are empty i.e. which are not filled.