# Smoothing MODIS LAI?

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis, time-series, smoothing

I am trying to smooth 8 days LAI data from MODIS and managed to work around it with several algorithms such as [loess](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279354/ndvi-time-series-with-missing-values), [Savitzky–Golay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843942/smoothen-rasterstack-using-the-savitzky-golay-sgolayfilt-signal-in-r/37846229#37846229), `smooth.spline` etc. This is pretty much going well if the level of noise is not really high (please see below plot) for a target feature.

[image]

However, for some pixels (i.e. features), the level of noise is so high that I am not sure if the fitted smooth line is realistic or not (please see below plot)?!

[image]

I have already filtered low-quality MODIS pixels using QA dataset but still no improvement.

Is there any suggestion for me how to smooth values of such pixels with high levels of noise?